# Is there any UI Automation tools available for iOS that don't require the iOS SDK

Tags: iphone, sdk, licensing, automation

Is there any UI Automation tools available for iOS that don't require the iOS SDK?

I'm wondering if there's a way for a tester to not have to download the SDK and have to accept the license agreement. All the Automation tools I have found require you to have the SDK downloaded.

Thanks

Comment: Aren't testers some kind of UI testing automation anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it seems that there isn't such thing.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Vladislav, pity, hopefully tools start coming out in the near future or Apple can change their licensing for testers, or an XCode for testers ...

Comment: @Brian: If you want to see this as a feature, please file a feature request at bugreport.apple.com. Tell them exactly what you need and why, and then post the radar to openradar.appspot.com too so other people might file the same request so that it get a higher priority over there at Apple.